# Calling the controller correctly from JavaScript - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I am using d3js library to draw charts. Here is I'm calling the action like this :

```
d3.json("CANCEL_REASON/Statistics2", function (data) {
....
```

My controller is like this :

```
 public class CANCEL_REASONController : Controller
    {
        private Entities3 db = new Entities3();

        public ActionResult Statistics()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Statistics2()
        {

        ///...
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When I debug the JavaScript, I realize that it's trying to call :

> http://localhost:12345/CANCEL_REASON/CANCEL_REASON/Statistics2

When I change js to this :

```
d3.json("/Statistics2", function (data) {
....
```

It's trying to call this :

> http://localhost:12345/Statistics2

How should I modify my code so that it will call this :

> http://localhost:12345/CANCEL_REASON/Statistics2

Thanks.

Comment: Try `/CANCEL_REASON/Statistics2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Url.Action` razor helper in order to obtain the correct path.

`@Url.Action` generates a fully qualified URL to an `action` method.

```
d3.json('@Url.Action("Statistics2","CANCEL_REASON")', function (data) {
```

Or simply

```
d3.json('/CANCEL_REASON/Statistics2', function (data) {
```

Comment: `@Url.Action` won't be accessible if above code is written in `.js` file

Answer (score 1):

Add a leading slash and you should be good to go:

```
d3.json("/CANCEL_REASON/Statistics2", function (data) { ... }
```

Then your path will relative to the root.